# Chrome Extension: Skipping red page on created tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.tabs.create({ 
    'url': 'https://www.myserver.com/', 
    'selected': false 
}, function(tab) { 
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { 
        'code': "doSomething();" 
    }); 
});
```

Actually I'm unable to execute the code, because there's invalid 
certificate on the "myserver.com", so Chrome displays red page, which 
I'm unable to skip and run my code. 
Is there any way how to skip the red page except adding the 
certification authority to trusted = except any neccessary step on the 
client side?

Comment: Not until you go to the site yourself and accept the invalid certificate. Chrome should remember your choice for that domain and allow the extension to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot inject or manipulate that page, due to security reasons. Which makes sense since that page is there to protect the user :)

The only way to do something like that is through Native Code, NPAPI. You implement a plugin that bypasses it. But as you know, implementing a plugin makes the whole computer vulnerable since you will have access to the entire host machine.

That is why creating plugins is not favoured, but recommended if you absolutely cannot do what you wanted with the current API and limitations.